# Darf man „Wuff“ bei Scrabble legen?

Tags: duden

Ich spiele grade Scrabble mit jemandem, der meint, er dürfte „Wuff“ legen, weil es im Duden steht; aber das möchte ich nicht akzeptieren.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the rules of a game.

Comment: Beachtet, dass das nicht meinungsbasiert ist, denn die Scrabbleregeln legen eindeutig fest, dass alle im Duden Band 1 verzeichneten Wörter (und nur diese) mitsamt ihren Beugungsformen gelegt werden dürfen. Die Frage reduziert sich darauf, ob *Wuff* im Duden steht.

Answer (score 4):

Ja, "Wuff" ist auf der Webseite des [Scrabble Deutschland e.V.](http://scrabble-info.de/) im Turnier-Checker zu finden. Auch auf [Wort-Suchen.de](https://www.wort-suchen.de/woerterbuch/wuff) wird es für Scrabble mit 3 Referenzen gefunden.

Answer (score 0):

Ja darf man. Wuff steht im Duden und muss damit akzeptiert werden. Da war dein Freund wohl sehr kreativ ;) Ich kann mir aber vorstellen, dass ihr sehr viel diskutiert habt. In solchen fällen rate ich euch einfach abzustimmmen.

Comment: Nur so nebenbei: Nicht jedes Wort, das im Duden steht, ist in Scrabble erlaubt. Eigennamen beispielsweise nicht. Ich gehe jetzt nicht auf die Details der Scrabble-Regeln ein, da gibt es andere Diskussionsplätze, aber einfach "steht im Duden -> ist erlaubt" geht nicht.